# Java Swing: components not added to JPanel with JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, tablelayout

This code is just a silly example which I need to understand to solve a much bigger problem about another project I am working on: as you can see, in the for cycle, 23 buttons are supposed to be added to JPanel. As they cannot be shown all together I decided to add a JScrollPane but a strange thing happens: only 19 are shown and I do not understand why. The size matrix has 1 column for 23 rows so it is correct. Do you know why this happens? Thanks

```
package proveGUI;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.ScrollPaneConstants;

import layout.TableLayout;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String argv[]) {

      JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Protocollo UTL");
      //jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
      jframe.setSize(1200, 450);

      JPanel body = new JPanel();
      double[][] size = {
              {0.05},
              {0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05,0.05}

      };

      body.setLayout(new TableLayout(size));

      for(int i=0; i<22; i++) {
          body.add(new JButton(String.valueOf(i)), "0,"+String.valueOf(i));
      }

      JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(body,
              ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED,
              ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);

      jframe.add(scrollPane);
      jframe.setVisible(true);

  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Try to use `body.setLayout(new BoxLayout(body, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));` instead of `TableLayout`

Comment: Works with `GridBagLayout`

Comment: @SeniorJD: thanks, this seems to work. Would you please tell me the difference and where I was making mistakes? But the problem is that in this way I can add items only in one colum...instead in my real project I have many rows and columns. How can I do that now?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I started with tablelayout by Oracle because I am at the first experience with Swing and GUI in general and somebody told me that library was simple and good. Why does it not work?

Comment: Nitpick: You're only adding 22 buttons, BTW.

Comment: ok, as I said this was just a silly example to solve my real problem...how can I specify the columns too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from you using size values between 0.00 and 1.00. These are interpreted as relative sizes/percentages, in this case 5%. That's why it's showing 20 rows only (0 to 19 inclusive). Try using "50.0" instead and the problem goes away. Or use `TableLayout.PREFERRED`.

Comment: Oh thank you very much! It seems I have just solved my problem at last. I would never ever have thought I was supposed to use integer values. Thank you from heart!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about `TableLayout` because I've didn't ever use it. If it is your first experience with Swing, try the [common Swing Layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

For your case, you can simple try

```
body.setLayout(new BoxLayout(body, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); // instead of TableLayout
```

When U'll understand how layouts work in Swing, use `GridBagLayout`, because it is the most adjustable layout.